# como printar as tags <td> no php

Tags: php

**fiz de dois jeitos:**

queria colocar a tag `<td>` no abreTD e `</td>` no fechaTD quando eu printasse na página, o problema é se eu simplesmente colocar as tags, elas somem.

```
while ($campo = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $coluna = $campo["Field"];
     echo '$html .= ' . '\'abreTD\''. ' . ' . '$'.  $coluna . ' . ' . '\'fechaTD\''. ';';
     echo "<br>";
}
```

A única forma que encontrei de printar é criando uma textarea e mandar printar dentro, daí dá certo, o problema é que não tem a **quebra de linha**, como eu faço pra printar dentro da textarea com quebra de linha? tentei fazer

`echo nl2br('$html .= ' . '\'<td>\''. ' . ' . '$'.  $coluna . ' . ' . '\'</td>\''. ';');`
mas não deu certo.

```
echo "<textarea class='textoarea' style='width: 100%; height: 60%;'>";
while ($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $coluna = $result["Field"];
    echo '$html .= ' . '\'<td>\''. ' . ' . '$'.  $coluna . ' . ' . '\'</td>\''. ';';
}
echo "</textarea>";
```

Comment: tente utilizar a função [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.htmlentities.php) com `echo htmlentities('<td>....')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não sei se entendi o que você quer, mas você quer que quando realizar um print screen ou imprimir a página apareça a tag "td" na página ? Se for isso você pode fazer de duas formas:

**Escapar a entidade HTML**
Substitua `<` por `&lt;` e `>` por `&gt;`

**Utilize tags HTML de exibição de código**
Utilize a tag `<code>Seu código HTML aqui que não será renderizado pelo navegador</code>`

Answer (score 0):

Por quê tem um echo '$html'?

Pelo que entendi você está querendo concatenar algum conteúdo na variável $html, que já deve ter algo. Assim sendo, o correto seria:

```
$html = 'conteudo inicial';
$html.= '<table><tr><td>conteudo da table</td></tr></table>';
echo $html;
```

Comment: `echo $table;`? de onde veio essa variável?

Comment: na verdade eu só estou puxando do banco os dados, montando os dados e jogando nas tags tds, daí é só eu copiar e colar (a table já está criada com seus respectivos trs)

Comment: Eu usei a variável errada. Já corrigi.

Independente da origem, o procedimento é o mesmo.